# Substitute pattern between braces

Tags: substitute

Is there a way to substitute a pattern only if it occurs inside the brace pair that the cursor is on?

For instance, if I have the text

```
int bar()
  {
  ...
  }

int foo()
  {
  char bar;

  bar = 'a';
  }
```

I can change all instances of bar to baz in the second brace pair using line numbers, e.g. `:7,11s/bar/baz/g`. Is it possible to do this without the line numbers, only having the cursor on one of the braces?

**Edit:**

The version of Vi I have is 3.10, which doesn't appear to have visual mode

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## First Solution

---

This requires some advanced `cmdline-range` magic to work. Here is what I have come up with:

```
:?{?,/}/s=bar=baz=g
```

Now, to break it down:

- `?{?` - Searches backwards for the first line containing a `{`.  You can
    use any regex in the place of `{` if you need to match more specific
    cases.
- `,` - This takes the lines in front of and in back of it, and matches
  all lines in between.
- `/}/` - Searches forwards for the first line containing a `}`.  Once again,
  this could be any regex to match your specific needs.
- `s=bar=baz=g` - This is just a normal search and replace statement, using
  `=` as the seperator.

Note that you must have the cursor between the two parentheses, otherwise it will not work.  These two help pages are very useful on the subject of `cmdline-ranges`:

```
:help 10.3
:help cmdline-ranges
```

## Second Solution

---

There is also a slightly simpler way of doing it as well.  These are the keys you have to press:

```
vi{:s/bar/baz/g
```

Here is how this works:

- `vi{` - Visually select an "inner block".  See `:help text-objects` for
  more on this.
- `:` - Key to start a command as usual, however when in visual select mode,
  vim automatically inserts markers for the beginning and ending of the 
  selection.  Like so: `:'<,'>`  This is more special `cmdline-range` syntax,
  where `'` means the line at marker `<`, which in this case is the marker
  which is always set to the beginning of the visual selection.
- `s/bar/baz/g` - Normal substitution command.

Comment: The first solution works great. The second solution didn't work for me, probably because the version of vi I am using is 3.10

Comment: After using the first solution here some, I realized that it flops when there are inner pairs of brackets.

Comment: Indeed it does.  It is a very simple solution, so I figured there would be some disadvantage to it.  I'll see what I can do to make it work, but it might end up being extremely complex.